# nmap - how to find port forwarding to SSH

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, nmap

I have a firewall that forwards port 2222 to a Linux machine running SSH server on port 2222.  The problem is I do not know what the IP of the firewall is.  So I want to scan the subnet to tell me which IP has this forwarded port.

I tried this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i=2; i<256; i++));
do

        sudo nmap -sS -p2222 10.1.$i.0/24
done
```

The output of this is a lot of this:

```
Host is up (0.00039s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
2222/tcp open  EtherNetIP-1
```

For 256x256 hosts this is what I see.  I think this answer could be one of two answers:

1. What *should* the output be?  Maybe I missed it and must `grep` for it.
2. What is a different `nmap` scan I should use?

Answer (score 2):

If the answer is still needed, I hope this will help.
Nmap supports multi-host scanning, for reference see [Target Specification](https://nmap.org/book/man-target-specification.html).
You can modify your command like so:

```
sudo nmap -sS -p2222 10.1.2-255.0/24
```

This will scan subnets from 2 to 255, like your loop did.